Tailwind style Select Item in next js issue
I want to stylize with tailwind CSS the SELECT item on my project but it does not work, the browser (Safari) keeps showing it as "Default with color" it shows only the select item like this, the other components on my project works perfectly fine.
CODE:
<select className='bg-white border border-gray-400  block' onChange={handleChange("currency")} value={currency}>
    <option value='Q'>Q</option>
    <option value='$'>$</option>
</select>
    

The item:

